# POST request cypress for-loop

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm writing a script to test automatic. First I create a shipment with random items. After that I make a POST request. Everything is working fine, but the POST request keeps giving the same data. But my console prints other data.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? Is it maybe impossible to do POST requests in a for loop?

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

describe('Create random shipments, Sign in, scan items, to transit', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/')
    })
    it('Sign in, scan items, to transit', () => {
        const username = '<username>'
        const password = '<password>'

        // Create default shipment
        const shipmentText = '{'+
            '"content": [],' +
            '"date": "2022-05-05",' +
            '"sender": { "company": "61d609e319b2c600129f71bb", "location": "61d609e319b2c600129f71bc" },' +
            '"receiver": {},' +
            '"orderNumber": "123456-20",' +
            '"transportNumber": "TransportNumber {{routeNaam}}",' +
            '"transportStopNumber": "Stop1",' +
            '"note": "<noteText>"}';
        const shipment = JSON.parse(shipmentText);
      
        // Create locations Test20, Test19, Test17
        const text = '{"locations":[' +
        '{"company": "6228be12e4a3460011f94c13","location": "6228be12e4a3460011f94c14"},' +
        '{"company": "6228a461e4a3460011f94676","location": "6228a461e4a3460011f94677"}]}';
        const objLocations = JSON.parse(text);

        // Create coreItems from .....
        const itemText = '{"items":[' +
        '{"coreItem": "6138c0ec64f3ea001196e5aa","quantity": 0,"status": "WHOLE","uniqueIds": []},' +
        '{ "coreItem": "6138bff564f3ea001196e540", "quantity": 0, "status": "WHOLE", "uniqueIds": [] },' +
        '{ "coreItem": "6138bfa464f3ea001196e51c", "quantity": 0, "status": "WHOLE", "uniqueIds": [] },' +
        '{ "coreItem": "619e4fe2485d2b00112d0262", "quantity": 0, "status": "WHOLE" }]}';
        const objItems = JSON.parse(itemText);
        const laagCoreId = "6138c0ec64f3ea001196e5aa"
        const middelCoreId = "6138bff564f3ea001196e540"
        const hoogCoreId = "6138bfa464f3ea001196e51c"
        const opzetCoreId = "619e4fe2485d2b00112d0262"


        // Loop through the different companies
        for (let i = 0; i < Object.values(objLocations.locations).length; i++) {
            // Get company id and location
            const element = Object.values(objLocations.locations)[i];
            cy.log("company:" + element.company, "location:" + element.location)

            // Loop through different coreItems
            for (let i = 0; i < Object.values(objItems.items).length; i++) {
                // Create random quantity between 1 - 10
                Object.values(objItems.items)[i].quantity = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
                let uids = []
                let qty = 0
                // Check item
                // Create for each quantity a uid
                if (Object.values(objItems.items)[i].coreItem == laagCoreId) {
                    qty = parseInt(Object.values(objItems.items)[i].quantity)
                    for (let i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
                        let uid = 20000000+Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000) + 1;
                        uids.push(String(uid))
                    }
                }
                else if (Object.values(objItems.items)[i].coreItem == middelCoreId) {
                    qty = parseInt(Object.values(objItems.items)[i].quantity)
                    for (let i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
                        let uid = 30000000+Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000) + 1;
                        uids.push(String(uid))
                    }
                }
                else if (Object.values(objItems.items)[i].coreItem == hoogCoreId) {
                    qty = parseInt(Object.values(objItems.items)[i].quantity)
                    for (let i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
                        let uid = 40000000+Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000) + 1;
                        uids.push(String(uid))
                    }
                }
                // Add uids array to coreItems
                Object.values(objItems.items)[i].uniqueIds = uids
            }
            // Copy shipment
            let copyShipment = shipment
            // Change content to coreItems with qty and uids
            copyShipment.content = objItems.items
            // Cange receiver
            copyShipment.receiver = Object.values(objLocations.locations)[i]
            cy.log(JSON.stringify(copyShipment))


            
            cy.request({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '<url>',
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',  
                  'api-token'    : '<token>',       
                },
                body: copyShipment
              })
            .should(
                (response) => {
                  expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
                },
              )
            .then(
                (response) => {
                  cy.log(JSON.stringify(response))
                }
              )
            
        }
    })
  })
```

Comment: Which lines do you mean by "POST request keeps giving the same data" and "console prints other data"?

Comment: I loop through two locations and give random data to the shipment. The console prints two times different data, that is what I want. But the post request upload two times the data from the last shipment.

Answer (score 0):

For loops don't work nicely with asynchronous commands like `cy.request()`, but without running it I would expect the code you have to work.

One quick trick to try is to wrap the `cy.request()` in a `cy.then()`. This defers the request setup and hopefully gives you the correct `copyShipment` value each time.

```js
...
cy.log(JSON.stringify(copyShipment))

cy.then(() => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '<url>',
    headers: {
      ...
    },
    body: copyShipment
  })
  .should(...)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tried it, but it's still not working...